# Test Run Result steps and Test Run Result Summary Details but unable to find any API related

Tags: azure, azure-devops

i am trying to fetch the attachments of the Test Run Result steps and Test Run Result Summary Details but unable to find any API related to that is i need the attchments for Test Run Result Steps and attachments id, for Test Run Result Summary

Answer (score 0):

A test case describes the steps to take when you run a test. Test suites are groups of test cases, and a test plan is the collection of test suites that need to be run for a particular iteration or release. Test points are the pairings of test cases with test configurations that need to be run for the test plan. A test run consists of a set of test points. The results are the outcome of running the tests in the test run.

Check out the doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Work with test attachments programmatically using the REST APIs for Azure DevOps Services and Azure DevOps Server
and what you need specifically is at the website
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/get-test-run-attachment-zip?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0